# how to copy a string chars from the end to the beginning in c language

Tags: c, string, function

`{ "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" }` I want this string to be something like 
`{"cccc", "d", "aaa", "bb"  }`. I have tried to switch index and it didn't work as well. What may this cause be?

```
char *str;
str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
int r;
printf("please enter the number of the rotations");
scanf("%d", &r);
rewind(stdin);
gets(str);
rotate(str, strlen(str), r);///the function is a void func and 
                            ///I want it to change the indexes in the main string 
puts(str);
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`, never *ever* use it! It is a dangerous function and for that reason have been removed from the C specification. Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: As for your problem, *what is your problem?*  Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Just to be clear - you're asking about an **array** of strings (this is not a single string. I'm not sure that I got what you wanted - do you want to simply swap places inside the array?

Comment: i wnat to move the last r chars from the string arrays to the beginning of the string array

Comment: Don't you have any code for `rotate` that you could post?

Comment: they have gived me this function void rotate(char* arr[], int len, int r);

Comment: the question is about rotating the last r chars to the beginning for example:
{ "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" } to {"cccc", "d", "aaa", "bb"} 
and they gived me this function to use  void rotate(char* arr[], int len, int r)

Comment: In a comment you that you want to move the last r chars to the beginning. However, the example in your question doesn't do that. Please clarify

Comment: Please state what is your exact input (both r and str) and what is your expected output

Comment: The variable `str` is an array of characters. What you probably mean with e.g. `{ "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" }` is an array of *strings*. Two very different things.

Answer (score 3):

The form of a single *[C string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)* would be:

```
{ "aaa, bb, cccc, d" } //single, comma delimited C string
```

But what you are showing:

```
{ "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" } //four C strings
```

depicts a collection of 4 strings, each *string* being an array of chars terminated by a null character.  Furthermore:

```
 char *str;
 str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*N);
```

creates a container to hold only a single string.

But the scenario you describe suggests you require variable that 
 can contain multiple strings, for example one of these 3:

```
 char **array  //used to create pointers to pointers of space. requires dynamic allocation.
 char *array[4]; // creates pointers to an array of strings. requires no dynamic allocation in this application.
 char array[4][5] // creates a 2D array, each with space enough for the longest string. No dynamic allocation require.
```

With modifications the following can be adapted to use either of the other 2 forms but for simplicity, this illustration uses the `char *array[4];` form. (Note also, the prototype for rotate is improvised given the lack of information in your post about what the function actually does.)

```
void rotate(char *sa[4], int rotate); 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *strArray[4] = { "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" };

    rotate(strArray, 1); 

    getchar();

}

void rotate(char *sa[4], int rotate)
{
    int i, j, count;
    char *temp = {0};
    //get count of elements
    count = sizeof(*sa)/sizeof(*sa[0]);

    for(i=0;i<rotate;i++)
    {

        temp = sa[0];
        for(j=0;j<count-1;j++)
        {       
            sa[j]=sa[j+1];
        }              
        sa[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: @4386427 -  I am editing some additional content....

Comment: Beware, you are proposing a 2D array, while rotating an array of string is simpler to implement with an array of pointers: `char * strArray[] = { "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" };`

Comment: @ryyker: the point on using a array of pointers is that you never copy strings. You just change in the pointer array the value of pointers to point to the new string

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Agreed.  Edited with your suggestion. Yes, much simpler approach. Thanks again.

Comment: Removed my comment and replaced DV with UV. I'm still not sure this is what OP is asking for. I'm not sure either that OP is looking for my kind of answer. :-) Anyway, OP seems to have lost interest so we probably won't find out.

Comment: @4386427 - Thank you,  appreciate your input, and I agree, shots in the dark are risky, but they help to wake me up in the morning. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear so I'm not sure this what you are looking for but let's give a try.

I assume you want to input a string with the format `{ "str1", "str2", ..., "strN" }`

That is a string which contains what could be considered double quoted substrings.

Then you want to be able to rotate these double quoted substrings.

A quick and dirty implementation could be as shown below.

**Notice**: The code does nearly **no error checking** - that must be added. However, I omitted the error checking to make the code shorter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getStrCount(char* str)
{
    int found = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == '\"')
        {
            ++found;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return found/2;
}

void getStrN(char* str, int N, int* start, int* end)
{
    int found = 0;
    int i = 0;
    *start = 0;
    *end = 0;
    while(str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] == '\"')
        {
            ++found;
            if ((found % 2) == 1) 
            {
                *start = i;
            }
            else
            {
                *end = i;
                if (found == 2*N) break;
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

void rotate(char* str, int r)
{
    int start, end;
    int words = getStrCount(str);
    r = r % words;
    if (r == 0) return;
    char* result = malloc(1024);
    strcpy(result, "{ ");
    char* w[words];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<words;++i)
    {
        w[i] = malloc(1024);
        getStrN(str, i+1, &start, &end);
        memcpy(w[i], &str[start], end-start+1);
        w[i][end-start+1] = '\0';
    }
    int j=words-r;
    for (i=0; i<words;++i)
    {
        if (i != 0) strcat(result, ", ");
        strcat(result, w[j]);
        ++j;
        if (j == words) j = 0;
    }
    strcat(result, " }");
    strcpy(str, result);
    free(result);
    for (i=0; i<words;++i)
    {
        free(w[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int r;
    int start, end;
    char str[1024];
    fgets(str, 1024, stdin);
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("Words: %d\n", getStrCount(str));
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("Rotate: %d\n", r);
    rotate(str, r);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT:

```
{ "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" }
2
```

OUTPUT:

```
{ "aaa", "bb", "cccc", "d" }
Words: 4
Rotate: 2
{ "cccc", "d", "aaa", "bb" }
```